# Groovy: @Immutable results in Setters

Tags: groovy

I'm having trouble with (or I'm confused about) using `@Immutability`.

Given this class:

```
@Immutable
class TestField {
   String key
}
```

I would expect I could not set a key on an instance like:

```
class TestFieldSpec extends Specification {

    def 'do stuff'() {
        when:
        def t = new TestField('a')
        println t

        t.key = 'b'
        println t

        then:
        t
    }
}
```

However, when I run the test, I do not see a `ReadOnlyPropertyException`:

```
Running TestFieldSpec
TestField(a)
TestField(b)
```

This has been the case for me using both the **groovy-eclipse-compiler** and **gmaven-plus** with **Maven**.
Groovy version *2.4.7*.

If I run **javap** on the class file created by both, I see:

```
public final void setKey(java.lang.String);
```

When I do the same in **GroovyConsole** though, things work how I'd expect them to.

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class TestField {
    String key
}

def f = new TestField('a')
f.key = 'b'
```

Produces:

Exception thrown

```
groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: key for class: TestField
    at TestField.setProperty(ConsoleScript1)
    at ConsoleScript1.run(ConsoleScript1:7)
```

In the **Groovy AST Browser**, at **Phase** *Finalization*, I do not see the setter.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run the tests from the command line?  (I assume you're using gradle or maven)...  Also are you sure you don't have two classes called `TestField`, one `org.oclc.cataloging.cr2.base.record.field.TestField` which isn't immutable, and another on that you've added the annotation to?

Comment: Using Maven, yes.  I get the output above.  There is one TestField.class, that is created.  I just now edited out the package names though in my post for the usual reasons, that was my bad.

Comment: Can you try the fully qualified `@groovy.transform.Immutable` in your `TestField` class...  Also, `TestField` is a Groovy class, yes?

Comment: Yeah, `TestField` is Groovy.  Same result with a fully qualified use of the annotation.

I just now used Spring Initializr to create a Groovy project and then removed all the Spring Boot stuff from the result.

I added a class like the above and a test, and I *DO* get a `ReadOnlyPropertyException`.  I *javap* the class and I do not see a setter.  So maybe something I'm doing in the original project is confusing things up.. I will look further.

Comment: Ah, I then added a dependency on `org.gcontracts:gcontracts-core` and the setter shows up in the created class file, and there is no exception!